# How to throttle http connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, networking, qos

I am looking for a way induce latency in my http REST connection. I need to find a solution to a an issue on the serveur side which terminates connection when bd connection pool is saturated (no more bd connection object can be created). I tested in my own and was not able to reproduce the issue. The issue happened in the production environment. I suspect that this happened because data came in late and sever had to to wait and hold bd connection so it can finish the task.

The way I tested was with a Java unit test which sent json data 1000 to the server. I didn't get to break the back-end.

My next approach is to do the same thing with some latency added over http to simulate a real life event where internet connection is not always stable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to induce latency on the server side, you can sleep the thread for some time before answering the HTTP request. For example:

```java
// NOT FOR PRODUCTION
@RequestMapping("/endpoint")
@ResponseBody
public String endpoint() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep this thread for 1 second
        return "Responded after 1 second";
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { // sleep was interrupted
        return "Responded before 1 second";
    }
}
```

If you want to induce latency on the client, you may need some custom handling to sleep the thread before reading from the client's socket.

Another option would be to introduce real latency at the lower network layers rather than the application layer. You may find some third-party tools helpful in that approach.

Comment: I am looking for some software that would really suck the bandwidth because the 1 second sleep is not very close to if the bandwidth would be available at 25% or 50%. During sleep nothing happens compared low bandwidth availability where data can still travel.